# Android: playing audio files in /res/raw by file name

Tags: java, android, file, audio

In my application's /res/raw/ folder, I have: `file1.ogg file2.ogg ... fileN.ogg`

In a local database, I have the references to the file names, i.e. `file1 file2 ... fileN`.

Given one of those strings, say `fileM`, how can I play the audio contained in `fileM.ogg`? Looking for the relevant Java code here.

Here's what I looked at so far:

```
String name = "plumber";
String link = "/res/raw/" + name + ".ogg";

try {
    mp.setDataSource(link); //earlier: mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(PlayScreen.this, "ERROR: audio player not working.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```

I get the error message in the toast. Also I've tried the `link` string without "/res/raw" in it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw" + filename;
try {
     player.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(path));
     player.prepare();
     player.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

try it with or without the extention ".mp3"

hope i could help you

Comment: Yep I think that's the right idea. I found this website to be helpful as well: http://en.kuma-de.com/blog/2011-11-14/341

Comment: i am sorry i gave a downvote,now i cant change it...please edit ur answer and notify me so that i can upvote..

Comment: You can also try `MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(path))` , which is more succinct than instantiating the `MediaPlayer`, then setting its data source, and then calling `prepare`.